# How do you change vs studio directory?

Tags: java, powershell, maven, visual-studio-code, cmd

I was trying to run my maven java project in the VSCode PowerShell terminal, with this command
`mvn package`, but I get this error:

```
& : The term 'c:\Users\milop\OneDrive\Documents\Personal Github Repositories\StockAnalysis-1\libs\mvn.cmd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I noticed that the directory for mvn.cmd was completely wrong being:
`c:\Users\milop\OneDrive\Documents\Personal Github Repositories\StockAnalysis-1\libs\mvn.cmd`
and it should have been:
`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.5\bin\mvn.cmd`

My question is how do I fix this error? I do not know if this has to do with this error but when I click dependencies in my maven project it says backround process terminated with code 1 error.

I tried looking back at my environmental variable on my computer but everything is right there.
I also tried redownloading maven but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following setting:

```
"maven.executable.path": ""
```

[Official documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_maven), or search `maven` in the *Settings* panel for more related settings.